# Conditional merge on 2 huge pandas datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 dataframes as below:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'UserId':['U1','U1','U1','U2','U2','U3'],'End_Week':['1/6/2020','15/6/2020','6/7/2020','4/5/2020','18/5/2020','20/4/2020'],'Start_Week':['1/6/2019','15/6/2019','6/7/2019','4/5/2019','18/5/2019','20/4/2019']})

B = pd.DataFrame({'UserId':['U1','U1','U1','U1','U2','U2','U3'],'Action':['U','V','U','U','V','V','U'],'Date':['5/3/2019','4/6/2019','1/7/2019','12/6/2020','4/4/2019','12/5/2019','19/3/2019'],'V1':[2,3,1,2,4,1,1],'V2':[0,1,0,0,1,2,1]})
```

I want to do the below steps:

For each row of 'A', find all corresponding rows from dataframe 'B' that fall between columns Start_Week and End_Week given in A. For example - 1st row of 'A' -> Start_Week is '1/6/2019' and End_Week is '1/6/2020'. All rows from dataframe 'B' that fall between these dates are 2nd and 3rd rows i.e. dates 4/06/2019 and 1/7/2019 (for User U1). Similar operation has to be done for all rows of dataframe A.

I have the below solution which works fine with small data but fails to allocate memory on the entire data I am using.

```
a = A.Date.values
a1 = A.UserId.values
b1 = B.UserId.values
bh = B.End_Week.values
bl = B.Start_Week.values

i, j = np.where((a1[:, None]==b1) & (a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] <= bh))
final_df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([A.values[i], B.values[j]]),columns=A.columns.append(B.columns))
```

I get the following error message:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 514. GiB for an array with shape (662195, 834051) and data type bool
```

A contains 662195 rows and B contains 834051 in my dataset.

Can someone help with a more optimal solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the dates to datetime (*Ignore this block if dates are already a datetime dtype*)

```
A[['End_Week','Start_Week']] = A[['End_Week','Start_Week']].apply(pd.to_datetime,
                                                                dayfirst=True)
B['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(B['Date'],dayfirst=True)
```

---

Then `merge` and use `series.between`

```
out = B.merge(A,on='UserId',how='left')
out = out[out['Date'].between(u['Start_Week'],u['End_Week'])]
```

---

```
print(out)

   UserId Action       Date  V1  V2   End_Week Start_Week
3      U1      V 2019-06-04   3   1 2020-06-01 2019-06-01
6      U1      U 2019-07-01   1   0 2020-06-01 2019-06-01
7      U1      U 2019-07-01   1   0 2020-06-15 2019-06-15
10     U1      U 2020-06-12   2   0 2020-06-15 2019-06-15
11     U1      U 2020-06-12   2   0 2020-07-06 2019-07-06
14     U2      V 2019-05-12   1   2 2020-05-04 2019-05-04
```

If you want only columns from B, you can filter the output to retain just columns from B;

```
out = out[out['Date'].between(u['Start_Week'],u['End_Week'])].loc[:,B.columns]
print(out)

   UserId Action       Date  V1  V2
3      U1      V 2019-06-04   3   1
6      U1      U 2019-07-01   1   0
7      U1      U 2019-07-01   1   0
10     U1      U 2020-06-12   2   0
11     U1      U 2020-06-12   2   0
14     U2      V 2019-05-12   1   2
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I tried merge operation (which you also suggested) but it kills the kernel due to memory sizing issues. I have 128 GB RAM available.

Comment: @Prateek How big is your dataset?

Comment: Around 20 millions rows with 15 columns. It is a user transaction data at date level.